# Print even numbers with array

Tags: data-structures

Assume that you have a global Array Arr of 5 elements, declare a function that checks if the element's values are even or not, and if it is an even element print “Yes” otherwise print “NO” and call it in the main function with an array element as attributes to check each element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```js
function isEven(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("Yes, it is even");
  } else {
    console.log("No, it is not even");
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let element of arr) {
  console.log(`Is ${element} even?`);
  isEven(element);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Is 1 even?
No, it is not even
Is 2 even?
Yes, it is even
Is 3 even?
No, it is not even
Is 4 even?
Yes, it is even
Is 5 even?
No, it is not even
```